# Received error 1004 for this entry on my VBA code

Tags: vba7

working on a loop that would run through all 6 sheets in a workbook.

expecting to get Total Stock Value

```vb
ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 7).Offset
(-TotalVolume), 0), (ws.Cells(i, 7)))
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)